# Failing inversion of control principle - single concrete class

Tags: inversion-of-control, solid-principles

I have a single concrete class: Validator that does a single thing.

I have no need to create an interface as there is only a single implementation of this.

Does this fail dependency of inversion principle when injecting instances of Validator into higher level classes?

If i am to use an interface for this class it causes a naming problem

Comment: *If i am to use an interface for this class it causes a naming problem* - What do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

We use interfaces because they help for swapping implementations, mocking during unit testing and of course abstraction.

> Does this fail dependency of inversion principle when injecting
>   instances of Validator into higher level classes?

According to [DIP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle), `Validator` should implement `IValidator` and classes needing it should just know about `IValidator` contract, not `Validator` definition itself. However, IOC containers (ex. [Unity](https://github.com/unitycontainer/unity)) allow you to register class types instead of interface.

It's just a principle and there could be valid exception to not follow it as-is. In cases like you, I would focus more on the core intention of DIP, IOC and [DI](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection); and that is to have loosely coupled code. I would hesitate to create interface if I am sure there's going to be just one implementation.

I would just make sure that nothing except my IOC container instantiates `Validator`.